# Been trying to automate the Find and Replace in Google Sheets but did not work

Tags: regex, google-apps-script, google-sheets

My sheet is a query-sheet from database. Some of them contain html hex-code color which I need to manually use edit>Find and Replace every time it is refreshed.

I am very new to Google App Script and been trying to use the following code:

```
function Clearcode() {
  var lookupone = new RegExp(/{color:#.{7}/);
  var rep = "";
  var spreadSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var querySheet = spreadSheet.getSheetByName("QUERY");
  var lastRow = querySheet.getLastRow();
  var lastColumn = querySheet.getLastColumn();
  var data = querySheet.getRange(2, 1, lastRow-1, lastColumn).getValues();
  var textfinder = querySheet.createTextFinder(lookupone);
  var found = textfinder.replaceAllWith(rep);
  return (found);
}
```

Yet, when I run this function in the sheet it did not work. Any thought?

P.S. I planned to eliminated "[color]" part of the hex-code as well by create the similar function.

P.S.2 I have attached a snapshot of a table as you requested. The red line is just for confidentiality of the data. Below the line is just a normal text.

[image: A snapshot of the sheet]

Comment: Can you share a sample copy of your sheet ?

Comment: Provide a screenshot of your data or a ascii table

Comment: I have uploaded the screenshot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pay attention to `type`s!

- [CreateTextFinder](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#createTextFinder(String)) accepts `String` as argument NOT a regexp object.
- To use strings as regular expressions, [`useRegularExpressions`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/text-finder#useRegularExpression(Boolean)) needs to be set to `true`

```
querySheet.createTextFinder("\\{color:#?.{0,6}\\}")//only 6 characters
  .useRegularExpressions(true)
  .replaceAllWith("")
```